# WPF: Using interface as DataContext instead of object implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I've refactored my WPF application so that the DataContexts are no longer instances of some class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` but rather some custom interfaces of mine.  The object that implements each custom interface is required to also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.    But I can no longer enforce this requirement at build time.  I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

For example, consider the following simple class hierarchy

```
// Base view model class has stock implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

public BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // Assume INotifyPropertyChanged implementation with this utility to raise the event

   void RaisePropertyChanged(string property) { // ...blah blah blah ... }
}

// Interface for nameable object

public interface INameable
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

// View model for nameable object

public class NameableViewModel : BaseViewModel, INameable
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (value == _name) return;
            _name = value
            RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

// Main view model exposes named object by interface, NOT by view-model

public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public INameable NameableObject { get; set; } 
}
```

Here's a view binding to `INameable` instead of `NameableViewModel`

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyView" 
             (... blah blah blah... namespace declarations...)
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance MainViewModel}">

    <TextBox DataContext={Binding NameableObject.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</UserControl>
```

This works fine in WPF because it queries any data context for `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  It receives the PropertyChanged notifications even though all it got was `INameable`.  But if I forget to set up my classes right, WPF will just silently never get property changed notifications.  I might end up having errors that take a while to notice or track (testing resources are limited here).

Furthermore, in my code-behind, I sometimes manually monitor some objects via  `INotifyPropertyChanged` using Josh Smith's excellent `PropertyObserver`.

```
public class PropertyObserver<TPropertySource> 
    : IWeakEventListener
    where TPropertySource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   ... blah blah blah..
}
```

This ***does*** require INotifyPropertyChanged at build time, and that was great when I was using instances of my BaseViewModel.  But now that I merely have an interface, I must query it myself and rely on a run-time error to let me know I've screwed up.

Which leads me to my questions.  One general and one very specific:

1. Is this design reasonable?  It it something done commonly in practice by people working in WPF?  Or is it generally always better to be sure that whatever type I use as a data context is something already declared to implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  (I realize I might be thinking too much like a C++ programmer with that question)
2. Suppose in my code, I cast an object and it does NOT support an interface I require and I want to throw an exception.  What specific .NET exception should I throw?  What's most appropriate?  `NotSupportedException`?  Something else?

Comment: "Is this design reasonable?" - sure. Even if you would enforce INotifyPropertyChanged there would be no guarantee that a particular implementation always fires the PropertyChanged event when it is supposed to do.

Comment: True , but I would far rather worry that they have not implemented it correctly than have to worry about whether they've implemented it at all

Comment: I don't need the code reviewed.  It's sample code.  I need to know if people do this in practice or not.  And my second question is very specific.

Comment: @Clemens Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: BTW in its current form, this post is currently [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CR because the title doesn't describe what it does and it has some code missing/commented out... See ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: I will admit struggling with how to word the title and not have it be 3 sentences long.  The sample code was merely intended to illustrate the pattern

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Sorry, I always thought that the close as off-topic reason "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" just shows an example list of other site. Retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the "design" or "practice" that you refer to is. I don't see a general pattern, only a specific use of an interface, for which its purpose is not clear to me.

In my experience, it's best to keep the view models as simple as possible. In some cases, they don't even need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (think of a read-only view model). Generally, I use an MVVM framework (such as MVVM Light Toolkit) that provides a `ViewModelBase`. Almost every view model I make derives from `ViewModelBase`, and the view model simply contains setters, getters, and commands.

For your second question, I think the specific exception depends on the intent for the use of the interface. But perhaps a general exception could be `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: The pattern to which I refer is exposing INotifyPropertyChanged by *contract* rather than by strong type;  Forcing future developers to have to *remember* to implement INotifyPropertyChanged because they're passing around interfaces like "INameable" rather than strong, ViewModelBase-derived types that they *know* implement INPC.  Maybe some guy works on this codebase, implements INameable but  forgets to implement INPC and wonders what went wrong.   I like to prevent such problems by design if I can

Comment: Anyway I might have made this moot by experimenting with deriving my custom interfaces (like INameable) from INotifyPropertyChanged themselves.  Now, any object that implements my INameable must derive from a my BaseViewModel class which does.  (Or it could implement INPC manually).  This seems to achieve what I want.    I will see how this goes.  Appreciate the suggestion for the exception to throw.

Comment: @Joe Yes, having `INameable` derive from `INotifyPropertyChanged` may achieve what you want. That design had crossed my mind, but I figured you wanted to keep `INameable` as simple as possible. But, again, it all depends on your intent for having the interface. You may as well name it `INameableViewModel` (and derive from `INotifyPropertyChanged`) if your intent is to use it on view models that must have a `Name` property. The `ViewModel` suffix would give developers the hint that it derives from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that it should be used on view models.